# How to destructure an array of objects into multiple arrays of its keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-destructuring

My data set is an array of objects which all have only two keys (`id` and `name`):

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'Foo'}, { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}, { id: 3, name: 'FooBar'}, { id: 4, name: 'BarFoo'}]
```

I want to destructure them in such a way that I end up having an id-array and a name-array respectively:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] // ids
['Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar', 'BarFoo'] // name
```

I did it this way but I think it can probably be done better with destructering:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo'}, { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}, { id: 3, name: 'FooBar'}, { id: 4, name: 'BarFoo'}]

let ids = []
let names = []
data.forEach(obj => {
  ids.push(obj.id)
  names.push(obj.name)  
})

console.log(ids)
console.log(names)
```

Comment: May be you can do `data.forEach(({id, name}) => { ids.push(id); names.push(name); })`.

Comment: Destructuring can't help you here since you have a dynamic number of elements. Because destructuring involves declaring variables it cannot be dynamic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo'}, 
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}, 
  { id: 3, name: 'FooBar'}, 
  { id: 4, name: 'BarFoo'}
]

const {ids, names} = {ids: arr.map(a => a.id), names: arr.map(a => a.name)}

console.log(ids)
console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
data.map(x => x.id)
data.map(x => x.name)
```

to get arrays

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo'}, { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}, { id: 3, name: 'FooBar'}, { id: 4, name: 'BarFoo'}];

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((res, { id, name }) => {
    res.ids.push(id);
    res.names.push(name);
    return res;
  }, { ids: [], names: [] })
}

const {ids, names} = formatData(data);

console.log("ids: ", ids);
console.log("names: ", names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo'}, { id: 2, name: 'Bar'}, { id: 3, name: 'FooBar'}, { id: 4, name: 'BarFoo'}];

const ids = data.map(({ id }) => id );
const names = data.map(({ name }) => name );

console.log("ids: ", ids);
console.log("names: ", names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Upvote for doing it in a single pass (in your 1st example) :)

Comment: I like the `reduce` approach 